# Capturing a popup window and download url using casperjs

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, screen-scraping, casperjs

I am trying to scrape a table from an aspx site using casperjs (a wrapper on phantomjs).  One of the table items I need is a link which opens a new page and downloads the PDF.  The contents of the TD tag are:

```
<input type="image" src="images/document.png" alt="View Document" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$mbody$tcManageDocs$tpViewDocs$gv_formData','View$1');return false;">
```

Once clicked, I have determined that it opens a new window to download the file.  Using wireshark, I have captured (relevant parts of) the response to the __doPostBack POST request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.open('documents/path/to/document.pdf', 'popup_window', 'width=1024,height=768,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=1,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes');popup_window.print();//]]>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'Menu1', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script></form>
```

However, when executing the link:

```
    this.click('#mbody_tcManageDocs_tpViewDocs_gv_formData > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)');
```

I get a **Page Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: popup_window** error when I try to run this.

Is there any way I can capture the window using javascript?

Do I need to capture it in the page context or from the phantomjs/casperjs context?

The relevant data I want to capture is the url only (being 'documents/path/to/document.pdf') as a text stream:  I would rather not actually perform the download to reduce the bandwidth/server demand and script execution time.

Being this is my first scraping attempt and I'm trying to learn javascript at the same time, I am stumped as how to proceed:  even some direction as to what to try would be helpful.

**EDIT:** I have captured the events as commented by Artjom:  I don't get any notifications for the resource messages, but in **popup.loaded** I get the following:

```
popup.loaded
{
    "objectName": "WebPage",
    "title": "",
    "frameTitle": "",
    "content": "<html><head></head><body></body></html>",
    "frameContent": "<html><head></head><body></body></html>",
    "url": "about:blank",
    "frameUrl": "about:blank",
    "loading": false,
    "loadingProgress": 100,
    "canGoBack": false,
    "canGoForward": false,
    "plainText": "",
    "framePlainText": "",
    "libraryPath": "/usr/share/casperjs/bin",
    "offlineStoragePath": "/home/rob/.qws/share/data/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS",
    "offlineStorageQuota": 5242880,
    "viewportSize": {
        "height": 300,
        "width": 400
    },
    "paperSize": {},
    "clipRect": {
        "height": 0,
        "left": 0,
        "top": 0,
        "width": 0
    },
    "scrollPosition": {
        "left": 0,
        "top": 0
    },
    "navigationLocked": false,
    "customHeaders": {},
    "zoomFactor": 1,
    "cookies": [],
    "windowName": "popup_window",
    "pages": [],
    "pagesWindowName": [],
    "ownsPages": true,
    "framesName": [],
    "frameName": "popup_window",
    "framesCount": 0,
    "focusedFrameName": "popup_window"
}
```

Is there something in the casperjs/phantomjs that is failing?  I am starting to suspect that the error above is one of the main issues.  When I wait for the popup for a while, casperjs times out and I get no further resource events.

Comment: See if you can gather the necessary information from the `"resource.requested"` and `"resource.received"` events.

Comment: I added some notes on what I am getting.  It seems to me that the popup is just never fulling loading.  Is there something about the casperjs/phantomjs environment that would cause it to fail?  Any ideas for how I proceed to troubleshoot?